# RESTful API scenario

Tags: json, web-services, rest

I am asking about the scenario of a RESTful service in a particular case. Assume that this is a file delevery service. Users submit an order then after a period of time ( 1-10 min ) a pdf file is ready for them to download. So the basics I came with:

- user submits an order using GET method to the webservice ( edit: OR POST )
- webservice returns an `orderid` via `json` or `xml`
- some background and human process takes place ( 1 - 10 mins )
- user checks the status of the order by passing the `orderid` to the webservice
- if the order is ready then an `statusCode` and a `pdfLink` is returned to user
- else only the `statusCode` is returned (i.e still proccessing, failed, etc)

Now, the question about this scenario is that how often the user ( other website ) should try to fetch the status of one specific order?

Do we need to stablish a double side webservices ? like:

- server A submits the order to B
- B informes A that the order is ready to get
- A requests B for the `pdfLink`
- A transferes the pdf file from server B to A

Comment: Just curious, why is there a 1-10 min gap between requesting for the PDF, and actually getting it?

Comment: There is no pdf at the first place, we produce the pdf based on the order. the PDF contains some custom data which might need human review to be ready.

Comment: Why does the user submit an order using GET? RESTful Apis map HTTP verbs to CRUD methods (create, read, update and delete). So surely your user should POST their data?

Comment: I see. @GrahamSmith has a point, too. Regarding "how often the user ( other website ) should try to fetch the status of one specific order," perhaps you can try adding something like a `checkAfter`, or `checkEvery` in your REST response that way, you may be able to suggest a course of action for the client.

Comment: @GrahamSmith ~ thats possible, I am asking about the consepts only here. But thanks for bringing this point out.

Comment: I'd use a POST for the initial order submit.  Possibly even HTTPS depending on what's in there.

Comment: Yes don't forget HTTPS for some basic security.

Answer (score 1):

When server A submits an order to B, it could also specify an url on which it expects a call if the order is ready. This way service B does not need to know the specifics of service A. It just calls the url specified by service A.

The response service B gives to service A, could also contain a url where to download the order.

This prevents polling from server A to server B, which significantly reduces the load on service B.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this would come handy.